# Sinatra gives me "not found" all the time instead of my page

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra, rack

Pretty simple Sinatra code

```
  get '/Accept/:value' do
    "Hello world"
  end

   not_found do
    "not found"
   end
```

when I go to `http://localhost:9292/Accept/?SomeKey=somevalue&Somekey2=someValue` Sinatra always returns "not found" back to me.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `SomeKey=somevalue&Somekey2=someValue` it will be present in the `params` if not wrong do only `/Accepts/` instead of `/Accept/:value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sinatra sees your url as `/Accept/` because you follow the last slash immediately with the `?` denoting the start of the query string.

A url like: `http://localhost:9292/Accept/foo?SomeKey=somevalue&Somekey2=someValue` will hit the get action, passing `foo` as `params[:value]`.

Comment: My url `http://localhost:9292/Accept/?SomeKey=somevalue&Somekey2=someValue` does not have foo before ? and I can't change it(this is a callback url), so I can't use your approach.